# osquery extension in Ruby - create new table

Tags: ruby, thrift, osquery

I'm trying to implement an extension for **osquery** in Ruby.

I found some libs and examples doing the same in Java, Node and Python, but nothing helpful implemented in Ruby language.

According to this documention, it's possible generating the code using Thrift: https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/osquery-sdk/#thrift-api

The steps I did, so far:

- Generated the code using `thrift -r --gen rb osquery.thrift`
- Created a class and some code to connect to the server and register the extension

This is the code of the class

```rb
# include thrift-generated code
$:.push('./gen-rb')

require 'thrift'
require 'extension_manager'

socket = Thrift::UNIXSocket.new(<path_to_socket>)
transport = Thrift::FramedTransport.new(socket)
protocol = Thrift::BinaryProtocol.new(transport)
client = ExtensionManager::Client.new(protocol)

transport.open()

info = InternalExtensionInfo.new
info.name = "zzz"
info.version = "1.0"

extension = ExtensionManager::RegisterExtension_args.new
extension.info = info

client.registerExtension(extension, {'table' => {'zzz' => [{'name' => 'TEXT'}]}})
```

To get the `<path_to_socket>` you can use:

```
> osqueryi --nodisable_extensions
osquery> select value from osquery_flags where name = 'extensions_socket';
+-----------------------------------+
| value                             |
+-----------------------------------+
| /Users/USERNAME/.osquery/shell.em |
+-----------------------------------+
```

When I try to get this table using `osqueryi`, I don't see the table when I run `select * from osquery_registry;`.

Have anybody by any chance implemented an osquery extension already? I'm stuck and I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've seen anyone make a ruby extension, but once you have the thrift side, it should be pretty simple.

As a tool, osquery supports a lot of options. So there's no single way to do this. Generally speaking, extensions run as their own process and the communicate over that thrift socket.

Usually, they're very simple and osquery invokes extensions directly with appropriate command line arguments. This is alluded to in the [doc](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/osquery-sdk/) you linked with the example accepting `--interval`, `--socket`, and `--timeout`. If you do this, you'll want to look at osquery's `--extensions_autoload` and `--extensions_require` option. (I would recommend this route)

Less common, is to start osquery with a specified socket path using `--extensions_socket`. And then your extension can use that. This way is more common is the extension cannot be a simple binary, and instead is a large complex system.

Comment: If you run into issues, there's a friendly osquery slack instance. https://join.slack.com/t/osquery/shared_invite/zt-h29zm0gk-s2DBtGUTW4CFel0f0IjTEw should join

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the Slack. I followed the doc you mentioned, I think because I'm not familiar with Thrift, it's hard to me to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself playing around with thrift via ruby. And it seems to work if I used a BufferedTransport:

```
socket = Thrift::UNIXSocket.new('/tmp/osq.sock')
transport = Thrift::BufferedTransport.new(socket)
protocol = Thrift::BinaryProtocol.new(transport)
client = ExtensionManager::Client.new(protocol)

transport.open()
client.ping()
client.query("select 1")
```